# How can i delete a certain row of data from my database

Tags: php, mysqli

I want to delete certain rows of data in my database. This is my code, it cant delete the data.Am i wrong in the get id part? i have set auto-increment id in my database table.

```
<form name="form1" action="" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <table>
        <tr>
            <td>select files</td>
            <td><input type="file" name="f1"></td>
        </tr>
        <td><input type="submit" name="submit1" value="upload"></td>
        <td><input type="submit" name="submit2" value="display"></td>
    </table>
</form>

<?php
$con = mysqli_connect("localhost","root","");
mysqli_select_db($con,"fyp")or die(mysqli_error($con));;
if(isset($_POST["submit2"]))
{
    $sql = "SELECT username, image FROM images where username = '$_SESSION[username]' ";
    $result = mysqli_query($con,$sql);
    echo"<table>";
    echo "<tr>";
    while ($row=mysqli_fetch_array($result))
    {
        echo "<td>";
        echo '<img src="data:image/jpeg;base64,'.base64_encode($row['image']).'" height="100" width="100"/>';
        echo "<br>";
        ?><a href = "delete.php?id=<?php echo $row['id'];?>" class = "delete">Delete</a><?php
        echo "</td>"; 


    }
    echo "</tr>";
}
```

code below is my delete.php

```
 <?php
$con = mysqli_connect('localhost', 'root', '');
mysqli_select_db($con,'images');
$id = $_GET["id"];
$sql = "DELETE FROM images where id =$id";
$result = mysqli_query($con,$sql);
?>


<script type="text/javascript">
window.location = "furprototype.php"
</script>
```

Comment: add id to select list `$sql = "SELECT id, username, image`

Comment: Thank you. your code is working. Thank you

Answer (score 1):

```
<?php
error_reporting(E_ALL);
mysqli_report(MYSQLI_REPORT_ERROR | MYSQLI_REPORT_STRICT);
$con = mysqli_connect('localhost', 'root', '','fyp');
$stmt = $con->prepare("DELETE FROM images where id =?");
$stmt->bind_param('i', $_GET["id"]);
$stmt->execute();
```

You should be using **prepared statements** for the database interaction, and a  proper **error reporting** should be always set, to warn you about wrong database selection and various sorts of typos, like a missed column in the field list.